# Print values only in list of tuples to csv file

Tags: list, csv, tuples, python-3.6

I have a small program that works, but not quite what I want.

The top half works fine.

The write (bottom) half does work, but all I am interested in is the values
in the tuples.  Nothing else.

My code:

```
import json
import csv

jsonfile = "f:\mark\python\data.json"

with open(jsonfile, "r") as jfile:
    jfile_decode = json.load(jfile)
    # Create a list of tuples with a list comprehension
    jlist = [[(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k in ['city', 'state', 'population', 'rank']] for d in jfile_decode]
    # print(jlist)  - Just for testing to make sure the output is what I wanted -


outputfile = "f:\mark\python\data.csv"
with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    csv_out.writerow(['city', 'state', 'population', 'rank'])
    for row in jlist:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

The output I am currently getting:

```
city state population rank

"('city', 'New York')" "('population', '8405837')" "('rank', '1')" "('state', 'New York')"

"('city', 'Los Angeles')" "('population', '3884307')" "('rank', '2')" "('state', 'California')"

"('city', 'Chicago')" "('population', '2718782')" "('rank', '3')" "('state', 'Illinois')"

"('city', 'Houston')" "('population', '2195914')" "('rank', '4')" "('state', 'Texas')"
```

What I want is this:  (Just the tuple values.  Nothing else)

```
city state population rank

'New York' 'New York' '8405837' '1'

'Los Angeles' 'California' '3884307' '2'
```

Comment: Can you show what `jfile_decode` looks like?

Comment: The first two lines:[{'city': 'New York', 'growth_from_2000_to_2013': '4.8%', 'latitude': 40.7127837, 'longitude': -74.0059413, 'population': '8405837', 'rank': '1', 'state': 'New York'}, 
         {'city': 'Los Angeles', 'growth_from_2000_to_2013': '4.8%', 'latitude': 34.0522342, 'longitude': -118.2436849, 'population': '3884307', 'rank': '2', 'state': 'California'},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eval the string, and get the element you want:

```
outputfile = "f:\mark\python\data.csv"
with open(outputfile, 'w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    csv_out.writerow(['city', 'state', 'population', 'rank'])
    for row in jlist:
        csv_out.writerow(" ".join([col[1] for col in row]))
```

> Edit
>   To erase the double quotes inside the strings use .strip('!"'):

```
print(" ".join([col[1].strip('!"') for col in row]))
```

an example:

```
big_tuple = [{'city': 'New York', 'growth_from_2000_to_2013': '4.8%', 'latitude': 40.7127837, 'longitude': -74.0059413, 'population': '8405837', 'rank': '1', 'state': 'New York'},{'city': 'Los Angeles', 'growth_from_2000_to_2013': '4.8%', 'latitude': 34.0522342, 'longitude': -118.2436849, 'population': '3884307', 'rank': '2', 'state': 'California'}]

jlist = [[(k, v) for k, v in d.items() if k in ['city', 'state', 'population', 'rank']] for d in big_tuple]

for row in jlist:
    print(" ".join([col[1] for col in row]))
```

as result

```
New York 8405837 1 New York 
Los Angeles 3884307 2 California
```

Comment: Generates an error:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    csv_out.writerow(eval(str(row)[1]))
  File "<string>", line 1
    (
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: @MarkS I see, according to your comment, let me know if this is what you want, I made an update

Comment: @MarkS sorry, forget to convert the list into a single string, let me know, hope it helps

Comment: Damian, 99%.  For some odd reason I am seeing some of the values enclosed in double quotes.  When I look at jlist in the PyCharm debugger they are not there.  Every line is formatted consistently.          "New York" 8405837 1 "New York"

"Los Angeles" 3884307 2 California

Chicago 2718782 3 Illinois

Houston 2195914 4 Texas

Philadelphia 1553165 5 Pennsylvania

Phoenix 1513367 6 Arizona

"San Antonio" 1409019 7 Texas

"San Diego" 1355896 8 California

Dallas 1257676 9 Texas

"San Jose" 998537 10 California

Austin 885400 11 Texas

Comment: @MarkS try this print(" ".join([col[1].strip('!"') for col in row]))

Comment: Damian, that is putting a space between every single character.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150238/discussion-between-damian-lattenero-and-marks).

Comment: Damian,  I found out what the issue was.   CSV format was originally for comma-separated values. So data looks like

a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i

The thing is, what happens when the data itself contains a comma? The solution is to surround the field with double quotes. Thus:

a,b,c
d,"e,f",g
h,i,j

No matter what delimiter you use, you need the double quotes to indicate if the data contains the delimiter. So if your delimiter is a space, any field containing a space has double quotes around it.     So the fix was to use a tab as the delimiter:  csv_out = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')

Comment: I actually wanted a tab and did not realize I had a space as the delimiter.